# Accessing User's Windows NT throughout a N-Tier Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, active-directory, entity-framework-core

I am using asp.net boilerplate core mvc c# jquery web project. This project is broken up into layers (web, application, core, ef core). My question is how do you access a user's windows nt (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name) throughout the many layers of your project? For example, if I was to make an ajax call directly to my application layer (api) then how do I access windows nt. The User.Identity.Name should only be accessible in the web project. I'm thinking some type of class that contains the user's nt that is loaded on startup and somehow maintained and dependency injected into the application layer as needed. What is the recommended way?

**EDIT 1:**
I understand that if I was to post from my view back to my controller then I could get the user nt and pass it to my application layer. But, that does not account for when I make an ajax call directly to my application layer.
Also, I do know how to access PrincipalContext but as stated above I have to know the user nt of the current active user which is only present in the web layer.

Comment: are you familiar with `AD as well as PrincipalContext` have you tried to execute a simple google search..?

Comment: As you said, you can create an instance in web project with user info: domain, user name, roles, etc and pass that instance to another layers

Comment: MethodMan - If I am posting on StackOverFlow then one should assume I have tried a simple Google Search and cannot easily find an answer to my problem. If a simple Google search is the answer then please post a link so we can discuss if that truly is the correct answer.

Comment: H. Herzl - I agree with your answer if I posted from my view back to my web controller but I am not. I am making ajax calls directly to my Application/Web Api layer which does not have access to User.Identity.Name